# multiple virtual (diamond) inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I found the following code in "The Design and Evolution of C++" by Stroustrup:

```
class W
{
public:
  virtual void f();
  virtual void g();
};

class AW : public virtual W
{
public:
  void g() {}
};

class BW : public virtual W
{
public:
  void f() {}
};

class CW: public AW, public BW ***, public virtual W***
{

};

CW* pcw = new CW;
AW* paw = pcw;
BW* pbw = pcw;

void fff()
{
  pcw->f(); //invokes BW:f()
  pcw->g(); //invokes AW:g()
  paw->f(); //invokes BW:f() !
  pbw->g(); //invokes AW:g() !
}
```

It exemplifies mixin behavior ie. different classes adding behavior to a common base and which "know of each other".

Why does CW inherit from W directly (***, public virtual W***)?
I tried in VC2015 both with and without and it generates the same class layout.

Comment: So that it inherits only one instance of `W`?

Comment: @Charles I think virtual inheritance from W of AW and BW takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

From *The C++ Programming Language (Fourth Edition)* by Stroustrup (21.3.5, page 632):

> All parts of an object [CW] must share a single copy of [W]. Otherwise, we could get two parts of something derived from [W] multiple times... We avoid replication by declaring a base `virtual`: every `virtual` base of a derived class is represented by the same (shared) object.

---

> I tried in VC2015 both with and without and it generates the same class layout.

The reason that it's less important in this case is because `W` has no instance variables to replicate; all the methods within `W` were declared `virtual` anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to inherit from W directly, when it is already present in the inheritance tree and CW has access to any functions or instance variables it might have?